Proof that the friendship graph does not include a five-round cycle
I'm thinking of looking for another way to prove the friendship theorem, which is done by showing that the friendship graph doesn't include a five-round cycle.

If we prove this, it will be easy to show that the friendship graph does not include any suprater-triangular cycles and then the drawing consists only of triangles, then it will be easy to show that all triangles have a common vertex.
But in reality, proving the absence of a pentathlon is really difficult.
Note that I suppose the person basically doesn't know that the friendship graph looks like a windmill and wants to show it later, I tried to do that but it turns out that later the charts become large and difficult to work with, and I'm still not sure if you can make an argument by showing that a friendship graph that includes a pentagon cycle should have an infinite number of vertices, which is a contradiction because the theorem is concerned with finite graphs.

Define the friendship graph as one where every two vertices share exactly one common neighbor. It can be shown that such a graph contains a vertex adjacent to every other vertex (skipping this proof but Fox's notes are comprehensive). Consider a $C_5=v_0,\ldots,v_4$ in this graph. By our previous statement, there exists some $v$ adjacent to every $v_i$ for $i\in[5]$. But then,  $v_i$ and $v$ both share the neighbors $v_{i+1\mod5}$ and $v_{i-1\mod5}$, contradicting our definition.
Note: The proof I skipped is not trivial, but you seem to assume this in your definition of the friendship graph anyway. Also, in the notes you'll find that this is not true for infinite graphs.
